# GWT doGet() servlet return image byte array or image to client

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT file upload widget to upload the image and then http servlet to get the image into the database.

I am using the formPanel FormPanel.METHOD_GET to call my servelet doGet() and i  am getting the image and storing it in to the byte array. I am unsure how to get that back to the client?

client code

```
downloadPanel = new FormPanel();
downloadPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
downloadPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET);
downloadPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"downloadfile" + "?brandID="+ accountIdStr);
downloadPanel.submit();

downloadPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSubmitComplete(FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent submitCompleteEvent) {

                image.setUrl(" http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/gwt-mini.png");

               // image.setUrl(submitCompleteEvent.getResults());
                Window.alert(submitCompleteEvent.getResults());

            }
        });
```

server code

```
public class FileDownload extends HttpServlet {


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    UserAccount adminUserAccount = getAdminUserAccount(request);
    int accountId = adminUserAccount.getAccountID();

    byte[] b =  API.GetAccountManager().getCompanyLogo(accountId);
```

The byte array has the image in it. How can i get the byte array or image back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the response `Writer` to write the response back to client, like this:

```
byte[] b =  API.GetAccountManager().getCompanyLogo(accountId);
respose.getOutputStream().write(b);
```

It will write the bytes back to the client, and on the client side, you will need parse the bytes most likely from an `InputStream`.

Comment: it wont let me send the byte array only as a string

Comment: @piddler you are correct, previous example was for a `String`, not `byte[]`, my bad.
Edited the answer to use `getOutputStream()`, instead of `getWriter()`. Its write method accepts a `byte[]`.

Comment: i extracted the url from the string and i am seeing the image on the browser. Thanks